# Memory leak not detected by static analyzer

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I came across this piece of code

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"]];
[self.view addSubview:image];
image = nil;
```

Given that ARC is not used, I assume that it will lead to a memory leak on the `image` object.
Nevertheless the static analyzer doesn't catch that.

I'm wondering who is mistaken, the static analyzer or me, and I'd like a second opinion on that.

Does the above code actually leak?

Comment: I think it does. Are you sure the analyzer is aware of the lack of ARC?

Comment: Yes it is, since other leaks are correctly detected.

Comment: I have added your code to `viewDidAppear` and get the *"Potential leak of an object stored into 'image'"* warning if I analyze that code with Xcode 4.6.3. (I created a fresh "Single View Application" without ARC.)

Comment: Where is this code declared, in initWithFrame maybe ? And what xcode version are you using ?

Comment: @H2CO3 it turned out if you were right after all, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the one mistaken was me (duh!)

The application I'm auditing is pretty large, and I missed the fact that the developers enabled ARC with the `-fobjc-arc` flag on specific classes, including the one the above snippet is taken from.

Long live to the static analyzer!

Answer (score 0):

`self.view` has an array of pointers to its subviews that will keep your `image` accessible and keep the reference counter (used for ARC) above 0.

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 200);
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
NSLog(@"image=%@", image);
[image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"]];
[self.view addSubview:image];
image = nil;

UIView *v = [[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"v=%@", v);
```

When you put `self.view = nil;` the reference counter for `image` will drop and the memory will be free'd. I don't think you can create a leak this way :)

Comment: you definitely can. `image` will drop by 1, but it has also been raised by 1 when added to the view.

Comment: @user511: This is not correct. `[self.view addSubview:image]` increases the retain count of `image` by one. `self.view = nil` will decrease it again. But if the `alloc` is not balanced by a `release` then the image object will never be deallocated and therefore leak. (Assuming Manual Reference Counting)

Comment: @user511, that's the whole point of it. But in the end I was mistaken, as I explained in my answer